# Displaying woocommerce cart items on a page

Tags: woocommerce, cart

I am working with woocommerce in wordpress.. I can't get it to show the cart item name and the cost of the cart item.  Plus the total on a wordpress page.. can anyone help me?

The hooks for woocommerce are here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

and the codes that i've tried is :

```
<?php

/*
Display number of items in cart and total
*/

global $woocommerce;

echo "Items in cart: ".sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);
echo "<br />";
echo "Total: ".$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
global $woocommerce;
$cart = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;
foreach($cart as $item){
   $name = $item['data']->parent->post->post_title;
   $price = $item['line_total'] / $item['quantity'];
}
```